# Summing over a range of value in R (not using for loop)

Tags: r

How do you perform such summation in R?

```
sum_{i=1}^3 (x^2)

i=1 is lower bound
i=3 is upper bound
x^2 is the operation
```

So we will perform

1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2

Using standard loop:

```
tot <-0
for (x in 1:3) {
  tot <- tot + x^2
}
```

Comment: Is this a homework/assignment question? What have you tried?

Comment: This one is pretty straight forward in R but it smells of a HW assignment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I'll point out that to generate a vector containing the elements `1,2,3` you can do:

```
x <- 1:3
```

Secondly, R is a vectorised language - meaning if `x` is a vector and I do `x + 5` it'll add 5 to *each element* of `x` for me without needing a for loop.

```
# Recalling that "x <- x + 5" is the same as
for ( i in 1:length(x) ) {
    x[i] <- x[i] + 5
}
# try to do something that makes  x squared, i.e. x == c(1,4,9).
```

Thirdly, look at `?sum`, whereby `sum(x)` adds up all the elements in `x`.

Answer (score 4):

```
the_answer <- sum( (1:3)^2 )
```

For-loops are so last century.